# Java plugin in browsers

Tags: javascript

I am learning about scripting languages, so one thing which i came across is that why you need java plugin if all the modern browsers can understand all the three technologies like HTML,CSS and javascript.

Comment: why is this tagged javascript? java !== javascript

Answer (score 0):

[Java Applets](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/) require a plugin. The linked Java Applet Tutorial says (in part),

> A Java applet is a special kind of Java program that a browser enabled with Java technology can download from the internet and run. An applet is typically embedded inside a web page and runs in the context of a browser. An applet must be a subclass of the `java.applet.Applet` class. The `Applet` class provides the standard interface between the applet and the browser environment.

Also note that [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) is not [java](/questions/tagged/java), but Java does include a [JavaScript Engine](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/jf14-nashorn-2126515.html).

Comment: And in many cases, a Java applet also requires a browser that still supports them.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara Applets have always required a plugin. So it's more that the plugin has to be available for the browser and installed (and enabled).

Comment: Right, but not all browsers support plugins. Browsers are moving away from them, and many simply don't support the Java plugin. Poor choice of working on my part, I guess.